# Is it possible to get the value of an overridden NON static member variable of a parent class?

Tags: php

Is it possible to get the value of an overridden NON static member variable of a parent class?

I understand that to get the value of a STATIC member variable you use self::$var1 or ClassName::$var1, but how do you get the value of a NON static member variable?

For instance...

```
class One
{
public $var1 = 'old var';
}

class Two extends One
{
    public $var1 = 'new var';

    public function getOldVar()
    {
        //somehow get old var
    }
}
```

Thanks so much in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nope. Once you've overridden a non-static property value it's gone. You can't use the `parent::` syntax with non-static properties like you can with methods.

However, using the `static` keyword you can utilize PHP's late static binding capabilities to access a **static** parent property because the static values are bound to the class in which they're assigned:

```
class Top
{
  public static $prop = 'Parent';
}

class Child extends Top {
  public static $prop = 'Child';

  public static function getParentProp() {
    return parent::$prop;
  }

  public static function getProp() {
    return static::$prop;
  }
}

echo Child::getParentProp(); // outputs "Parent"
echo Child::getProp();       // outputs "Child"
```

Note that you cannot override a non-static property with a static one in a child class to achieve what you're attempting because PHP (and all other scripting languages, I believe) uses the same table to store property names. This is just a limitation of the language.

Answer (score 5):

You can do this using reflection:

```
class One {
    public $var1 = 'old var';
}

class Two extends One {
    public $var1 = 'new var';

    public function getOldVar() {
        $ref = new ReflectionClass(get_parent_class());
        $props = $ref->getDefaultProperties();
        return $props['var1'];
    }
}

$two = new Two;
var_dump($two->getOldVar());  // string(7) "old var"
```

Comment: You're right but it's kind of a bastardization of the language. A ReflectionClass is not really a parent class -- It's a separate entity entirely. It would be like making a robotic model of my father and acting as if it were actually my dad. Which, on second thought might not be so bad :)

Comment: Your metaphor is incorrect, of course.  A `ReflectionClass` instance is more like a report detailing everything about your father.  It doesn't pretend to *be* your father.

Comment: You're correct, though I think your distinction illustrates my point: a ***report*** about what a class can do probably shouldn't be confused with what a class ***actually can*** do. Anyway, reflection is a valid answer.

Comment: I agree 100%.  And, for what it's worth, I have yet to come across a problem better solved by reflection than a change in design or approach, which is why I +1'ed your answer.

Comment: It's nice to encounter people who can objectively discuss various strategies for solving a problem without assuming they're being flamed for their answer. Reflection is something I hadn't thought of. I would avoid it for low-level functionality but if it's a one-off kind of thing or provides a feature that would be used rarely it might be really helpful. I would be afraid to implement in code that gets executed often in an application, though ...

Comment: Most definitely.  I think where reflection shines is meta-programming (a la [Doctrine 2 annotations](http://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/common/2.0/docs/reference/annotations/en)).  I don't think I'd ever use it for actual business application logic or things of that nature.  It was just the first thing that popped into my head when I read the OP, and when I saw the other answers all saying it couldn't be done, I couldn't resist. :-)

Comment: Hey thanks so much you two! By the way, the reflection stuff is too advanced for me. Atleast I learned that it reports information about a class. :-)